# how to count items in array - javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to count the data number in array in javascript, I used `Object.keys(results.data).length` but the result is **12** when I only have **2**

this is the data generated a library
[image]

how can I count this correctly?

Comment: looks like `data` is an array. So you can directly do `results.data.length`.

Comment: This is a typo. `lenght` -> `length`

Comment: [Please do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) -- [edit] your question, pasting all code [correctly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), preferably as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `data` is array, You can directly get with

```
results.data.length
```